# Python C Extension Nested Dictionary Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, dictionary, segmentation-fault, reference-counting

I am trying to create a Python (2.7.12) extension in C that does the following:

- Provide a read only nested dictionary with module level scope for the Python programmer.
- A background thread invisible to the Python programmer will add, delete, and modify entries in the dictionary.
- The extension will be built directly into the Python interpreter.

I created a simplified version of this extension that adds one entry to the dictionary and then constantly modifies it with new values. Below is the C file containing comments about what it is doing along with my understanding how the reference counts are being handled.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static PyObject *module;
static PyObject *pyitem_error;
static PyObject *item;
static PyObject *item_handle;
static pthread_t thread;

void *stuff(void *param)
{
    int garbage = 0;
    PyObject *size;
    PyObject *value;

    while(1)
    {
        // Build a dictionary called size containg two integer objects
        // Py_BuildValue will pass ownership of its reference to size to this thread
        size = NULL;
        size = Py_BuildValue("{s:i,s:i}", "l", garbage, "w", garbage);
        if(size == NULL)
        {
            goto error;
        }

        // Build a dictionary containing an integer object and the size dictionary
        // Py_BuildValue will create and own a reference to the size dictionary but not steal it
        // Py_BuildValue will pass ownership of its reference to value to this thread
        value = NULL;            
        value = Py_BuildValue("{s:i,s:O}", "h", garbage, "base", size);
        if(value == NULL)
        {
            goto error;
        }

        // Add the new data to the dictionary
        // PyDict_SetItemString will borrow a reference to value         
        PyDict_SetItemString(item, "dim", value);

        error:
        Py_XDECREF(size);
        Py_XDECREF(value);
        garbage++;              
    }

    return NULL;
}

// There will be methods for this module in the future
static PyMethodDef pyitem_methods[] =
{
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initpyitem(void)
{
    // Create a module object
    // Own a reference to it since Py_InitModule returns a borrowed reference
    module = Py_InitModule("pyitem", pyitem_methods);
    Py_INCREF(module);

    // Create an exception object for future use
    // Own a second reference to it since PyModule_AddObject will steal a reference
    pyitem_error = PyErr_NewException("pyitem.error", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(pyitem_error);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "error", pyitem_error);

    // Create a dictionary object and a proxy object that makes it read only
    // Own a second reference to the proxy object since PyModule_AddObject will steal a reference
    item = PyDict_New();
    item_handle = PyDictProxy_New(item);
    Py_INCREF(item_handle);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "item", item_handle);

    // Start the background thread that modifies the dictionary
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, stuff, NULL);
}
```

Below is a Python program using this extension. All it does is print out what is in the dictionary.

```
import pyitem

while True:
    print pyitem.item
    print
```

This extension seems to work for a while and then crashes with a segmentation fault. An examination of the core dump reveals the following:

```
Core was generated by `python pyitem_test.py'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  PyObject_Malloc (nbytes=nbytes@entry=42) at Objects/obmalloc.c:831
831             if ((pool->freeblock = *(block **)bp) != NULL) {
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f144a824700 (LWP 3931))]
```

This core dump leads me to believe the issue might have to do with my handling of the object reference counts. I believe this might be one cause since problems posed by others with the same core dump resolved the issue by properly handling reference counts. However, I do not see anything wrong with my handling of the object reference counts.

Another thing that comes to mind is that the print function in Python is likely only borrowing a references to the contents of the dictionary. When it is trying to print the dictionary (or access its contents in any other way), the background thread comes along and replaces the old entry with a new one. This causes the reference count of the old entry to decrease and the object is then removed by the garbage collector. However, the print function is still trying to use the old reference which causes an error.

Something that I found interesting is that I can change how quickly or slowly the extension has a segmentation fault by only changing the names of the keys in the dictionaries.

Does anyone have any insights as to what the issue may be? Is there a better way to create the extension and still have the properties that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found the cause of the segmentation fault. The background thread is modifying the state of the interpreter without obtaining the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). This would indeed cause the interpreter to behave in unexpected ways.

To fix this, I first call the function PyEval_InitThreads() in the module initialization function. The next thing to do is enclose any instructions in the background thread that make use of Python C API with the functions PyGILState_Ensure() and PyGILState_Release(). Below is the modified source code with this fix.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static PyObject *module;
static PyObject *pyitem_error;
static PyObject *item;
static PyObject *item_handle;
static pthread_t thread;

void *stuff(void *param)
{
    int garbage = 0;
    PyObject *size;
    PyObject *value;
    PyGILState_STATE state;  // Needed for PyGILState_Ensure() and PyGILState_Release()

    while(1)
    {
        // Obtain the GIL
        state = PyGILState_Ensure();

        size = NULL;
        size = Py_BuildValue("{s:i,s:i}", "l", garbage, "w", garbage);
        if(size == NULL)
        {
            goto error;
        }

        value = NULL;            
        value = Py_BuildValue("{s:i,s:O}", "h", garbage, "base", size);
        if(value == NULL)
        {
            goto error;
        }

        PyDict_SetItemString(item, "dim", value);

        error:
        Py_XDECREF(size);
        Py_XDECREF(value);

        // Release the GIL
        PyGILState_Release(state);

        garbage++;              
    }

    return NULL;
}

static PyMethodDef pyitem_methods[] =
{
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initpyitem(void)
{
    module = Py_InitModule("pyitem", pyitem_methods);
    Py_INCREF(module);

    pyitem_error = PyErr_NewException("pyitem.error", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(pyitem_error);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "error", pyitem_error);

    item = PyDict_New();
    item_handle = PyDictProxy_New(item);
    Py_INCREF(item_handle);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "item", item_handle);

    // Initialize Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)
    PyEval_InitThreads();

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, stuff, NULL);
}
```

The extension now runs without any segmentation faults.